# Formatting time error - "10.03" becomes "10.3"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a date and time that I format. It works most of the time, but if the time has a "0" in the second last space it will return wrong. For example, time "10.30" will be formatted correctly, but "10.03" will return "10.3" without the zero.

My code:

```js
const today: Date = new Date();
const date: Date = new Date(item.receivedDateTime);
let time: string;

if (date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() &&
  date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
  date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
  time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
} else {
  time = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

Above will format time incorrectly. What is wrong in the code? I prefer not to use padstart as it is not supported in IE11 or moment.js.

Comment: I think you have to use ldap function to add '0' before value minor to 9

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add an example of ìtem`

Comment: _“What is wrong in the code?”_ - well, technically nothing. You just didn’t make it do what you actually want. `getMinutes` returns an integer, so you can’t expect a leading zero to magically appear out of nowhere. So if you want one, you have to see to it that it gets added to the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value of `date.getMinutes()` in a variable and check if it's smaller than 10, and if so, append a `0`.

```
const minutes = date.getMinutes();
const formattedMinutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
```

Finally, use the formatted value for output:

```
time = date.getHours() + ":" + formattedMinutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple pad function

```js
const pad = num => ("0"+num).slice(-2);

const item = {"receivedDateTime":1570000000000}


const today =  new Date();
const date =   new Date(item.receivedDateTime);
let time = "";

if (date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() &&
    date.getMonth()    === today.getMonth() &&
    date.getDate()     === today.getDate()) {
 time = pad(date.getHours()) + ":" + pad(date.getMinutes());
} else {
  time = pad(date.getDate()) + "/" + pad(date.getMonth() + 1);
}
console.log(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
```

You can use,

```
var minutes = d.getMinutes() > 9 ? d.getMinutes() : '0' + d.getMinutes();
time = date.getHours() + ":" + minutes
```